# MultipartFile recieved null when using vs-upload to upload file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

I am using [vs-upload](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#default) to upload a file, this is the client code:

```
<div class="vx-row">
            <vs-upload data multiple="fasle" :headers="{'token' : token}" action="/service/zhuolian/report/org/user/import/list" @on-success="successUpload" />
        </div>
```

and this is the spring boot(2.x) server side code:

```
@PostMapping("/list")
Response<SparkUserImportResponse> orgUserImport(@RequestBody MultipartFile file,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false,value = "override",defaultValue = "false") Boolean override);
```

when I upload xlsx files in the browser, the server side received null MultipartFile. why the server side receive null? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

add fileName `file` for the upload component, the code looks like this:

```
<div class="vx-row">
            <vs-upload data fileName="file" multiple="fasle" :headers="{'token' : token}" action="/service/zhuolian/report/org/user/import/list" @on-success="successUpload" />
        </div>
```